# Android Graphical UI Builders - Connect event

Tags: android, user-interface, sdk

Maybe this question has been ask already, but could not find any answer for almost 2hours of internet search.

There is a graphical UI designer wich is coming along with the  last android SDK.

Looks pretty cool and well done.

Nevertheless I ***** cannot find how to attach an event to the control through the graphical editor.

Of course I can add it manually into the xml, but in that case, what's the purpose of having such tool without that function ?

I mean all the other SDK I had in other languages always include that function.

I've also not been able to find doc about how to use this tool. Quite sad...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a click event handler, select the button (widget) in the GUI that you want to listen for, and look for the property onClick.  Enter the name of the method you want to call when the user clicks on that widget, like.. onMyButtonClick

Then add the method to your Activity

public void onMyButtonClick(View v) {
   // I heard the button click
}

The GUI builder is getting there, and is not yet as easy to use as the one in XCode, but it's not hard when you get used to it.

Comment: Indeed that's it, damn, I've search for it but didn't think it would be located under "view". I've found one onto the parent class over the right click menu but did not work. Thanks